# How to add Devarts dotConnect provider to Entity Framework?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, devart, dotconnect

I'm trying to follow this Devarts tutorial of Entity Framework:
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/tutorial_ef.html

But when I try to create a connection of Entity Data Model, I cant find the dotConnect provider.

I already add that text in .config file

```
<provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" 
          type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=8.4.389.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
```

- Visual Studio version: 2013
- Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity version: 8.4.389.0
- Entity Framework: 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about versions, I was using Express version that not supports Entity Framework. You need Professional or Developer version if you want to use with Entity Framework:
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/editions.html

But here you can find more information about Provider Registration: 
http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html#ProviderRegistration